# AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded on aws linux ami 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, apache2.4

I am trying to bbot up amazon linux ami with django application from elastic beanstalk but it keeps saying `AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded`. Ngix options works fine but apache does not start. I am not sure why

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this exact problem when a new instance would spin up and it's due to there being no `LoadModule mpm_.......` in any `/etc/httpd/*/*.conf` file in the default AL2 image.

For me, the startup tasks kept looping (and failing) because it couldn't start httpd. I realized that one of my ebextensions had this:

```
services:
  sysvinit:
    httpd:
      enabled: true
      ensureRunning: true
```

This is why it kept trying to start httpd, which happens before the base httpd.conf file gets replaced by the one specific to my platform (Tomcat 8.5 + Java 8 in my case). I got rid of the `services` block above, which really isn't necessary for me, and that enabled the startup tasks to continue without httpd starting. A later step in the startup tasks will replace the base httpd.conf file which *does* include this directive: `LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so` and then httpd will be able to start.